# Can't remove geodesic lines from google map after drawing them

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, underscore.js

I'm trying to delete lines after drawing 10 and am pushing each marker and line into arrays during each repetition of `each` loop and then calling `for` loop to cycle through arrays and use `setMap(null)` on each but the markers and lines still stay there. How to remove them? I tried nesting `each` in a `for` loop and then replacing all `place.whatever` with `dataArray.places.whatever` and running second `for` loop with `var j` instead, but still didn't work.

```
var dataArray = {
    'places': [{
        'destinationLng': '-74',
        'sourceLng': '-91',
        'destinationLat': '40',
        'sourceLat': '38'
    }, {
        'destinationLng': '-104',
        'sourceLng': '-99',
        'destinationLat': '39',
        'sourceLat': '19'
    }, {
        'destinationLng': '18',
        'sourceLng': '-112',
        'destinationLat': '59',
        'sourceLat': '49'
    }, {
        'destinationLng': '-122',
        'sourceLng': '-91',
        'destinationLat': '37',
        'sourceLat': '38'
    }, {
        'destinationLng': '-74',
        'sourceLng': '-80',
        'destinationLat': '40',
        'sourceLat': '41'
    }, {
        'destinationLng': '-121',
        'sourceLng': '123',
        'destinationLat': '37',
        'sourceLat': '10'
    }]
};

function initialize() {     
    mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    el = document.getElementById('map');
    map = new google.maps.Map(el, mapOptions);

    console.log(dataArray.places.length);
    _.each(dataArray.places, function(place, index) {
        var markers = [];
        var geoLines = [];
        window.setTimeout(function() {          
            start = new google.maps.LatLng(place.sourceLat, place.sourceLng);
            endpt = new google.maps.LatLng(place.destinationLat, place.destinationLng);
            coords = [start, endpt];        
            var color = '#393';

            var lineSymbol = {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 8,
                strokeColor: color          
            };  

                source = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: start,
                    map: map,
                    icon: {
                        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                        scale: 8,
                        strokeColor: color
                        },
                    });
                markers.push(source);

                geoLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: coords,
                    strokeColor: color,
                    strokeOpacity: 2,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    geodesic: true, 
                    map: map,
                    icons: [{
                        icon: lineSymbol,
                        offset: '100%'
                    }]
                }); 
                geoLines.push(geoLine);

                animateCircle();
                animatePoly();
        }, index * 2500);
        for (var i = 0; i < place.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
            geoLines[i].setMap(null);      
        }
    });
}           

function animatePoly() {
    var step = 0;
    var numSteps = 250;
    var timePerStep = 1;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        step += 1;
        if (step > numSteps) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            var theMotion = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(start,endpt,step/numSteps);
            geodesicPoly.setPath([start, theMotion]);
        }
    }, timePerStep);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined`

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: line is not defined`

Comment: You are trying to remove them before you have added them.

Comment: The `_.each` is from Underscore and the `animateCircle` function is vestigial and should've been deleted before posting--sorry, my bad.

Comment: I don't get how they're not added though. The arrays are declared before the `window.setTimeout` function and have the markers and geodesic polylines pushed to them during the function. Shouldn't they be in the arrays by the time the `for` loop is used since they're added to the arrays in the function before?

Comment: Nope.  The setTimeout functions all run after the loop that would remove them if they had been added to the map. [jsfiddle that waits until they have been added to the map before removing them](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rccrjuc4/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the functions after the setTimeout can all run before the setTimeout function because of the delay? Sorry if I'm asking too many questions, I just want to understand for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop that removes the lines runs immediately after the loop that sets up the `setTimeout` calls that add the lines.  Those `setTimeout` calls delay then run the included function. So the timeline is:

1. loop sets up creation of polylines at various delays
2. loop to remove polylines runs
3. `setTimeout` functions run, adding the polylines to the map.

to remove them after they are added, use a `setTimeout` to remove the polylines with a delay greater than the largest delay to add a polyline (dataArray.places.length * 2500 should work).

**code snippet that removes the polylines *after* they are added:**

```js
var dataArray = {
  'places': [{
    'destinationLng': '-74',
    'sourceLng': '-91',
    'destinationLat': '40',
    'sourceLat': '38'
  }, {
    'destinationLng': '-104',
    'sourceLng': '-99',
    'destinationLat': '39',
    'sourceLat': '19'
  }, {
    'destinationLng': '18',
    'sourceLng': '-112',
    'destinationLat': '59',
    'sourceLat': '49'
  }, {
    'destinationLng': '-122',
    'sourceLng': '-91',
    'destinationLat': '37',
    'sourceLat': '38'
  }, {
    'destinationLng': '-74',
    'sourceLng': '-80',
    'destinationLat': '40',
    'sourceLat': '41'
  }, {
    'destinationLng': '-121',
    'sourceLng': '123',
    'destinationLat': '37',
    'sourceLat': '10'
  }]
};

function initialize() {
  mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  el = document.getElementById('map');
  map = new google.maps.Map(el, mapOptions);

  console.log(dataArray.places.length);
  var markers = [];
  var geoLines = [];
  dataArray.places.forEach(/* dataArray.places, */ function(place, index) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      start = new google.maps.LatLng(place.sourceLat, place.sourceLng);
      endpt = new google.maps.LatLng(place.destinationLat, place.destinationLng);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "line " + index + " start=" + start.toUrlValue(6) + " end=" + endpt.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
      coords = [start, endpt];
      var color = '#393';

      var lineSymbol = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 8,
        strokeColor: color
      };

      source = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: start,
        map: map,
        icon: {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          scale: 8,
          strokeColor: color
        },
      });
      markers.push(source);

      geoLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: coords,
        strokeColor: color,
        strokeOpacity: 2,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        geodesic: true,
        map: map,
        icons: [{
          icon: lineSymbol,
          offset: '100%'
        }]
      });
      geoLines.push(geoLine);

      // animateCircle();
      // animatePoly();
    }, index * 2500);
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "remove lines<br>";
    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.places.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
      geoLines[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }, dataArray.places.length * 2500);
}

function animateCircle() {
  var count = 0;
  window.setInterval(function() {
    count = (count + 1) % 200;
    var icons = line.get('icons');
    icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
    line.set('icons', icons);
  }, 20);
}

function animatePoly() {
  var step = 0;
  var numSteps = 250;
  var timePerStep = 1;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    step += 1;
    if (step > numSteps) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
      var theMotion = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(start, endpt, step / numSteps);
      geodesicPoly.setPath([start, theMotion]);
    }
  }, timePerStep);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="map" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```